# Testnet fallback nodes

Tags: fallback-nodes, testnet

Is there a list of nodes on Testnet that work like the fallback nodes on the Mainnet? I am trying to test my Bitcoin communication code and I'd like to start with just one IP I can rely to be on and responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blockexplorer.com runs a testnet node all the time.

Comment: So I would be connecting to 109.123.116.245:18333 ?

Comment: @ThePiachu That's correct now, but don't hardcode the IP address.